# Migrate / index / reindex mongodb into elasticsearch using express JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, elasticsearch

Trying to migrate the mongodb into elasticsearch using following [mongo-elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-elasticsearch) module.

```
var mongo-elasticsearch = require('mongo-elasticsearch');
var t = new mongo-elasticsearch.Transfer({
  esOpts: {
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
  },
  esTargetType: 'tweet',
  esTargetIndex: 'twitter',
  mongoUri: 'mongodb://abc123:def456@myhost.com:27747/dbname',
  mongoSourceCollection: 'tweets'
});

t.start().then(function(results) {
  process.exit();
});
```

I have used [reboundodm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reboundodm) module to index the document. Suggest me, how to re-index the document.

Comment: What specifically - Elasticsearch will index documents automatically on insert. And up there you're passing "esTargetIndex" - so it's going to use that right away. If you're looking into specifying some specific combination for elastic indexing, that's probably better done in your elastic-specific client (not sure about this `reboundodm` thing).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Zlatko, Initially I want to migrate all documents from mongodb into elasticsearch. Yes, I can migrate through mongo-elasticsearch module. End user can update the document, In this case I need to re-index the document in elasticsearch. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Well you just re-insert the document in elasticsearch. It will reindex it automatically.

Comment: @Zlatko I want to update the document using _id: "AVmCw4znHO6bFVnpAj-3". Is there any idea/suggestions

Comment: Well just put the document to the same id. But honestly that looks wrong. If you _do_ have an ODM (reboundodm in this case), then it should take care of those things. Check their docs, it's possible (and probable) that you're covered already.